# Bootstrap Hypothesis testing: Why Null and alternative hypothesis are not mutually exclusive?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, bootstrap

I'm new to hypothesis testing, and following an online tutorial which confuses me in the way they setup the null and alternative hypothesis, and compute the p-value.

My understanding is that null and alternative hypothesis must be mutually exclusive; so that if we can reject the null hypothesis, it should suggest the alternative hypothesis should be highly probable.

### Problem

There is a treatment and control group and we want to find out whether treatment has an effect.

**Test statistic**
Difference of means = $ \mu_{control} - \mu_{treated} $
Observed test statistic = 1.14

**Simulate null hypothesis and generate sampling distribution with bootstrapping**
bothMean = Concat control and treatment data and compute its mean.
control_shifted = $ control - \mu_{control} + bothMean $
treated_shifted = $ treated - \mu_{treated} + bothMean $

bootstrap replicates = Generate 10,000 samples from control_shifted and treated_shifted and compute difference of means.

Here is the histogram of bootstrap replicates:
[image]

So far so good!

**Compute p**
This is where I get confused:
p = #(bootstrap_replicates >= 1.14) / 10,000

Why are we only looking at the right tail and ignoring the left tail? I don't understand why we are computing the p-value like this in this problem.

Comment: The second hypothesis should omit the equality. Where are you seeing it written that way?

Comment: @Glen_b this is the answer provided in the problem.  Online tutorial is a pretty well known data science eduction platform, and this exercise is part of a tutorial for statistical inference.

Comment: Never heard of it. What's the URL? I hope that's just a really bad edit rather than an actual misunderstanding on their part but the two hypotheses should be mutually exclusive.

Comment: https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/statistical-thinking-in-python-part-2/introduction-to-hypothesis-testing?ex=1, the tutorial is behind a paywall.  One other thing I don't understand is why are we doing a one-tail hypothesis test. Isn't it also possible that the difference in means could be negative? Should I just discard this problem as a bad example and move on?

Comment: I was not discussing the p-value but the part about the hypothesis, which is now deleted from the question.

Comment: @Glen_b yes, my apologies. I got suspicious and checked the edit history, then realized my mistake.